# Square Payment Gateway integration in PHP website doesn't redirect to payment portal

Tags: javascript, php, payment-gateway, square

I m trying Square payment gateway using the API code found in the below URL

[http://significanttechno.com/square-payment-gateway-integration-using-php]

However, although i have replicated and tried to test the same code in my server, nothing seems to work.

The form doesn't allow me to input card details, and even if i add input tags to it and try to submit the form it doesn't redirect to action page..

The code goes as:

**Index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Square Payment Gateway</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"><![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- link to the SqPaymentForm library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform">
    </script>

    <!-- link to the local SqPaymentForm initialization -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sqpaymentform.js">
    </script>

    <!-- link to the custom styles for SqPaymentForm -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sqpaymentform-basic.css">
    <script>
     document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    if (SqPaymentForm.isSupportedBrowser()) {
      paymentForm.build();
      paymentForm.recalculateSize();
    }
  });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="form-container">
  <div id="sq-ccbox">
    <!--
      Be sure to replace the action attribute of the form with the path of
      the Transaction API charge endpoint URL you want to POST the nonce to
      (for example, "/process-card")
    -->
    <form id="nonce-form" novalidate action="payment-process.php" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <span class="label">Card Number</span>
        <div id="sq-card-number"></div>

        <div class="third">
          <span class="label">Expiration</span>
          <div id="sq-expiration-date"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="third">
          <span class="label">CVV</span>
          <div id="sq-cvv"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="third">
          <span class="label">Postal</span>
          <div id="sq-postal-code"></div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <button id="sq-creditcard" class="button-credit-card" onclick="requestCardNonce(event)">Pay $1.00</button>

      <div id="error"></div>

      <!--
        After a nonce is generated it will be assigned to this hidden input field.
      -->
      <input type="hidden" id="amount" name="amount" value="100">
      <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
    </form>
  </div> <!-- end #sq-ccbox -->

</div> <!-- end #form-container -->
</body>
</html>
```

**sqpaymentform.js**

```
// Set the application ID
var applicationId = "APPLICATION-ID";

// Set the location ID
var locationId = "LOCATION-ID";


function buildForm(form) {
  if (SqPaymentForm.isSupportedBrowser()) {
    form.build();
    form.recalculateSize();
  }
}
function buildForm1() {
    if (SqPaymentForm.isSupportedBrowser()) {
      var paymentDiv = document.getElementById("form-container");
      if (paymentDiv.style.display === "none") {
          paymentDiv.style.display = "block";
      }
      paymentform.build();
      paymentform.recalculateSize();
    } else {
      // Show a "Browser is not supported" message to your buyer
    }
  }
/*
 * function: requestCardNonce
 *
 * requestCardNonce is triggered when the "Pay with credit card" button is
 * clicked
 *
 * Modifying this function is not required, but can be customized if you
 * wish to take additional action when the form button is clicked.
 */
function requestCardNonce(event) {

  // Don't submit the form until SqPaymentForm returns with a nonce
  event.preventDefault();

  // Request a nonce from the SqPaymentForm object
  paymentForm.requestCardNonce();
}

// Create and initialize a payment form object
var paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({

  // Initialize the payment form elements
  applicationId: applicationId,
  locationId: locationId,
  inputClass: 'sq-input',
  autoBuild: false,

  // Customize the CSS for SqPaymentForm iframe elements
  inputStyles: [{
    fontSize: '16px',
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue',
    padding: '16px',
    color: '#373F4A',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    lineHeight: '24px',
    placeholderColor: '#CCC',
    _webkitFontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    _mozOsxFontSmoothing: 'grayscale'
  }],

  // Initialize Apple Pay placeholder ID
  applePay: false,

  // Initialize Masterpass placeholder ID
  masterpass: false,

  // Initialize the credit card placeholders
  cardNumber: {
    elementId: 'sq-card-number',
    placeholder: 'XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX'
  },
  cvv: {
    elementId: 'sq-cvv',
    placeholder: 'CVV'
  },
  expirationDate: {
    elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
    placeholder: 'MM/YY'
  },
  postalCode: {
    elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
    placeholder: '12345'
  },

  // SqPaymentForm callback functions
  callbacks: {
    /*
     * callback function: createPaymentRequest
     * Triggered when: a digital wallet payment button is clicked.
     * Replace the JSON object declaration with a function that creates
     * a JSON object with Digital Wallet payment details
     */
    createPaymentRequest: function () {

      return {
        requestShippingAddress: false,
        requestBillingInfo: true,
        currencyCode: "USD",
        countryCode: "US",
        total: {
          label: "MERCHANT NAME",
          amount: "100",
          pending: false
        },
        lineItems: [
          {
            label: "Subtotal",
            amount: "100",
            pending: false
          }
        ]
      }
    },

    /*
     * callback function: cardNonceResponseReceived
     * Triggered when: SqPaymentForm completes a card nonce request
     */
    cardNonceResponseReceived: function (errors, nonce, cardData) {
      if (errors) {
        // Log errors from nonce generation to the Javascript console
        console.log("Encountered errors:");
        errors.forEach(function (error) {
          console.log(' er= ' + error.message);
          alert(error.message);
        });

        return;
      }
      // Assign the nonce value to the hidden form field
      document.getElementById('card-nonce').value = nonce;

      // POST the nonce form to the payment processing page
      document.getElementById('nonce-form').submit();

    },

    /*
     * callback function: unsupportedBrowserDetected
     * Triggered when: the page loads and an unsupported browser is detected
     */
    unsupportedBrowserDetected: function () {
      /* PROVIDE FEEDBACK TO SITE VISITORS */
    },

    /*
     * callback function: inputEventReceived
     * Triggered when: visitors interact with SqPaymentForm iframe elements.
     */
    inputEventReceived: function (inputEvent) {
      switch (inputEvent.eventType) {
        case 'focusClassAdded':
          /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
          break;
        case 'focusClassRemoved':
          /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
          break;
        case 'errorClassAdded':
          document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Please fix card information errors before continuing.";
          break;
        case 'errorClassRemoved':
          /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
          document.getElementById("error").style.display = "none";
          break;
        case 'cardBrandChanged':
          /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
          break;
        case 'postalCodeChanged':
          /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
          break;
      }
    },

    /*
     * callback function: paymentFormLoaded
     * Triggered when: SqPaymentForm is fully loaded
     */
    paymentFormLoaded: function () {
      /* HANDLE AS DESIRED */
      console.log("The form loaded!");
    }
  }
});
```

**payment-process.php**

```
<?php 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$access_token = 'ACCESS-TOKEN';
# setup authorization
\SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setAccessToken($access_token);
# create an instance of the Transaction API class
$transactions_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\TransactionsApi();
$location_id = 'LOCATION-ID';
$nonce = $_POST['nonce'];

$request_body = array (
    "card_nonce" => $nonce,
    # Monetary amounts are specified in the smallest unit of the applicable currency.
    # This amount is in cents. It's also hard-coded for $1.00, which isn't very useful.
    "amount_money" => array (
        "amount" => (int) $_POST['amount'],
        "currency" => "USD"
    ),
    # Every payment you process with the SDK must have a unique idempotency key.
    # If you're unsure whether a particular payment succeeded, you can reattempt
    # it with the same idempotency key without worrying about double charging
    # the buyer.
    "idempotency_key" => uniqid()
);

try {
    $result = $transactions_api->charge($location_id,  $request_body);
    // print_r($result);

    // echo '';
    if($result['transaction']['id']){
        echo 'Payment success!';
        echo "Transation ID: ".$result['transaction']['id']."";
    }
} catch (\SquareConnect\ApiException $e) {
    echo "Exception when calling TransactionApi->charge:";
    var_dump($e->getResponseBody());
}
?>
```

Please note that i have download the **"Square SDK"** as mentioned and added **location ID and Access token** from Square account.

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Apologies to Every One who banged their heads at this issue and wasted their valuable time on this.,

Turns out the reason for this silly issue is **not having the site secured (i.e., Absence of SSL certification)**

I came to know about this after going through square-up documentation..

Anyway, Thanks to all.

Comment: Hi @harish-k -- I used your code exactly as it is and downloaded SDK too and put it on remote server with SSL - but am getting "The `Authorization` http header of your request was malformed. The header value is expected to be of the format "Bearer TOKEN" (without quotation marks), where TOKEN is to be replaced with your access token (e.g. "Bearer ABC123def456GHI789jkl0"). For more information"-- Can you Help???